# Codec used in a webRTC stream

Tags: video, video-streaming, webrtc, codec, opentok

When I use a webRTC-demo like the opentok-demo or the appear.in , what kind of video codec is used then ?
Or is it just the rawstream that is send. 
Did some research but i can't find a clear answer.

Comment: You can always check the negotiated and current SDP's from 'chrome://webrtc-internals' for Chrome. Thus you can see the decided codec and some more handful information like packet stats. Chrome to Chrome communication usually prefers VP8 as video codec.

Answer (score 3):

WebRTC has the following codec's:

Audio:

- Opus
- G.722
- ISAC
- PCMU
- PCMA

Video:

- VP8  (Chrome and Firefox)
- H.264  (legacy platforms)

So one of these are used. For browser to browser most probably the Opus codec is selected. For other directions it depends which of these are supported by the other party.

Comment: Thank you for the information , so if i set up a firefox to firefox connection it will be most likely VP8 that is used as codec.

Comment: Yes, it should be vp8.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 46 uses VP8 as priority codec for video and Opus for audio.